# Photoshop mask extension color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I frequently use predominately black masks on gradient or fill layers to show a shape with a color that I can choose later. However, when I transform the layer, the extension color is white- i.e. opaque. This leaves filled areas around the image where photoshop had to create more mask.

[image]

Anyway I can set this to fill new areas with black i.e. transparent?

[image]

Comment: In this scenario, you could avoid this issue by rasterizing each cloud layer instead. No layer mask, no color fill. Just a good ole raster layer. You wouldn't really lose anything by doing that in this situation

Answer (score 1):

Automatically? No.

You can simply select the areas and fill them manually. There's no automated method which I'm aware of that will arbitrarily fill non-masked areas. Photoshop, while powerful, can not make the decision of which areas are desired and which are not.

Comment: And I'd be seriously ticked off if it tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the layer and layer mask, just link them (select both, and click on "Link Layers").